# Android opengl es white screen on real device

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-virtual-device

On Virtual device all works fine. Where could be trouble?
Device - Nexus.
Maybe I need some features in manifest, or some glFunction error or texture format.
I use PNG texture(with/without alpha no matter)
Main parts of code:

Activity:

```
package com.example;
//imports
public class wheel extends Activity {
    private GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
    // some buttons, views
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mGLSurfaceView = (TouchSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.glsurfaceview);
        mGLSurfaceView.requestFocus();
        mGLSurfaceView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mGLSurfaceView.requestRender();
        // other interface
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

SurfaceView:

```
package com.example;
//imports
public class TouchSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public TouchSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mRenderer = new CylinderRenderer(context);
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
    public TouchSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        mRenderer = new CylinderRenderer(context);
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // some rotation
        requestRender();
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // some rotation
        return true;
    }
    private class CylinderRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
        public CylinderRenderer(Context context) {
            mCylinder = new Cylinder(0);
        }
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            gl.glTexEnvx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_MODULATE);
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glTranslatef(0, 0.3f, -2.5f);
            gl.glScalef(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);

            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

            gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID[5]);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
            gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
            gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
            mCylinder.draw(gl);
            requestRender();
        }
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
            float ratio = (float) width / height;
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);
        }
        private void loadTextures(GL10 gl) {
            int[] textures = new int[6];
            mTextureID = new int[6];
            int[] resources = {R.raw.a, R.raw.b, R.raw.c, R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f};
            gl.glGenTextures(6, textures, 0);

            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                mTextureID[i] = textures[i];
                gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID[i]);
                gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
                gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
                gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);

                InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(resources[i]);
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                    }
                }    
                GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
        }
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
            gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            loadTextures(gl);
            requestRender();
        }
        private Cylinder mCylinder;
        private Context mContext;
        private int mTextureID[];
    }

    private CylinderRenderer mRenderer;
}
```

Cylinder:

```
package com.example;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class Cylinder
{
    private final static int verticesCount = 40;
    private final static int indicesCount = verticesCount * 3;
    private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer mTexBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer  mIndexBuffer;
    private float vertices[];

    public Cylinder(int type)
    {
        vertices = new float[(verticesCount + 1) * 12];
        byte indices[] = new byte[indicesCount * 2];
        float texture[] = new float[verticesCount * 8 + 1];
        float tx, ty, dx, size, dz, dy;
        // generate indices, texture, vertices
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        mVertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mTexBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
        mTexBuffer.put(texture);
        mTexBuffer.position(0);

        mIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
        mIndexBuffer.put(indices);
        mIndexBuffer.position(0);
    }
    public void draw(GL10 gl)
    {
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTexBuffer);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount * 2, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mIndexBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: do u fix it ? can u tell me how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are probably not sized to a power of 2 value (e.g. 512x512 or 512x256 etc).

Comment: Oh god why:) I have read about size(2x4x8x16..), but on emulator all was fine and i forget it. I`ll check it right now, ty.